# Erro 500 no CakePHP versão 1.3.15

Tags: php, cakephp, apache, http, centos

Estou trabalhando em um projeto em *CakePHP* que eu não consigo testar em *localhost*.

Peguei o projeto já iniciado e como não consigo fazer os testes, posto direto mantendo sempre o backup e trabalhar assim é horrível.

Fiz a instalação do CakePHP na versão 1.3.15 que é a mesma que está no servidor e está funcionando perfeitamente. Consigo rodar qualquer versão do CakePHP, menos essa que está funcionando na web.

Fiz os teste num servidor virtualizado CentOs 6.7 rodando PHP 5.3.3 e o apache e mesmo assim não funcionou.

Alguém tem alguma sugestão?

Comment: Verifique o resultado do log, e se possível, edite a pergunta com ele.

Comment: Como que eu faço isso, @MarcelodeAndrade?

Comment: No diretório /app/tmp/logs/ deve haver um arquivo criado pelo próprio Cake.

Comment: Dá uma olhada se o debug (app\Config\core.php) está como no modo 2 ->  Configure::write('debug', 2);
Talvez ajude ver onde está o erro.

Comment: @MarcosXavier.
Ele está num if else.
Como deve ficar então?

'`if (stristr($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], 'servidor') === false)   
{  
 Configure::write('debug', 0);
}
else
{
 Configure::write('debug', 2);
}`'

Comment: @fabricio_wm Comente esse trecho que você citou e deixe com
Configure::write('debug', 2);
Em produção deixe
Configure::write('debug', 0);
Se funcionar comente aqui.

Comment: @MarcosXavier. Funcionou.
Agora eu vejo todos os erros. Como eu faço para te amostrar o print de tela?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalizado após dar o seguinte comando:

```
chmod -R 777 ArqRio
```

Answer (score 1):

Fabrício, o erro 500 é um erro interno do servidor. Tem que ver o que está no log.

Quando desenvolvo php sempre escolho fazer no linux. A minha indicação seria uma virtualização.

Sugiro você dar uma olhada no Linux Turnkey:

https://www.turnkeylinux.org/cakephp

Para iniciar um desenvolvimento, existe o OpenShift, da Red Hat, que é gratuito e, para testes e estudo, e é bem interessante. Depois de criar a conta, cria um *Application* usando o [projeto do GitHib CakePhp](https://github.com/openshift/cakephp-example)

Comment: Poxa, eu até sei fazer virtualização mas nesse computador eu não tenho essa opção.
Ele não é compatível com virtualização.
Vou ver o que faço.
Obrigado.

Comment: Mas tenho outros projeto em cake que funcionam nesse "Servidor".
Vc teria outra sugestão, @andre?

Comment: VirtualBox roda em qualquer computador. Você pode colocar 64 MB de memória e rodar tranquilamente.

Comment: A outra sugestão é você editar a pergunta como o Marcelo disse e compartilhar conosco o log.

Comment: Encontrei uma solução melhor para seus testes. Cria uma conta no openshift, da Red Hat, que é gratuita, e instancia o projeto do GitHib [link](https://github.com/openshift/cakephp-example) e usa para seu desenvolvimento.

Comment: O problema não é o Virtual Box ou VM e sim a máquina que não tem suporte a virtualização.
Gostei da ultima dica, @Andre. Vou testar.Obrigado.

Comment: Estou subindo uma máquina CentOs 6.7 modo texto e já vou postar os resultados aqui. Estou num note e subi via VirtualBox.
Obrigado.

Comment: consegui agora e funcionou no OpenShift mas eu fiquei mais grilado ainda pq no servidor CentOs que eu subi, não funcionou.
http://bkp-arqrio.rhcloud.com/
Será que é algum modulo do php ou do apache que não está ativo?

Comment: pode ser sim. Que bom que o OpenShift resolveu.

Comment: Adicionei à resposta a opção do OpenShift. Não esquece de marcar a solução como resposta correta. Abs.

Comment: Resolveu uma parte. Agora eu tenho um ambiente de testes. Gostaria de dar continuidade e fazer isso funcionar. Eu dei um `chmod 777 ArqRio` e infelizmente não resolveu.
Como que eu faço para verificar o log e descobrir o erro?

Comment: O link da aplicação é o http://arqrj-snjwebmobile.rhcloud.com/ mas eu preciso fazer funcionar no meu servidor local linux. 
A aplicação está com links que apontam para o site original e eu já verifiquei o routes.php e os controllers e os links estão da mesma forma mas com resultados diferentes.

Comment: O Marcelo sugeriu nos comentários da sua pergunta onde deve estar o log. Se não encontrar, tenta em /var/log/apache2/. Nesta pasta deve estar o log de erro e o de acesso. Boa sorte!